# ClassCastException: javax.swing.plaf.FontUIResource cannot be cast to javax.swing.InputMap

Tags: java, swing, components

Running a swing application in java, and I got this exception in my program. It's worth noting that this does not show up every time I run the program.

Full stack trace :

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at org.backend.utils.importing.Loading$1.run(Loading.java:54)
    at org.backend.utils.importing.Loading.loadEverything(Loading.java:61)
    at org.main.BishopCarrollSchoolTracker.main(BishopCarrollSchoolTracker.java:70)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: javax.swing.plaf.FontUIResource cannot be cast to javax.swing.InputMap
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.getInputMap(BasicButtonListener.java:102)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.installKeyboardActions(BasicButtonListener.java:78)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonUI.installKeyboardActions(BasicButtonUI.java:121)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonUI.installUI(BasicButtonUI.java:73)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.setUI(JComponent.java:662)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton.setUI(AbstractButton.java:1782)
    at javax.swing.plaf.synth.SynthArrowButton.updateUI(SynthArrowButton.java:34)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton.init(AbstractButton.java:2149)
    at javax.swing.JButton.<init>(JButton.java:118)
    at javax.swing.JButton.<init>(JButton.java:73)
    at javax.swing.plaf.synth.SynthArrowButton.<init>(SynthArrowButton.java:23)
    at javax.swing.plaf.synth.SynthScrollBarUI$2.<init>(SynthScrollBarUI.java:325)
    at javax.swing.plaf.synth.SynthScrollBarUI.createIncreaseButton(SynthScrollBarUI.java:325)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicScrollBarUI.installComponents(BasicScrollBarUI.java:225)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicScrollBarUI.installUI(BasicScrollBarUI.java:147)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.setUI(JComponent.java:662)
    at javax.swing.JScrollBar.setUI(JScrollBar.java:190)
    at javax.swing.JScrollBar.updateUI(JScrollBar.java:210)
    at javax.swing.JScrollBar.<init>(JScrollBar.java:144)
    at javax.swing.JScrollBar.<init>(JScrollBar.java:159)
    at javax.swing.JScrollPane$ScrollBar.<init>(JScrollPane.java:698)
    at javax.swing.JScrollPane.createHorizontalScrollBar(JScrollPane.java:794)
    at javax.swing.JScrollPane.<init>(JScrollPane.java:282)
    at javax.swing.JScrollPane.<init>(JScrollPane.java:305)
    at org.gui.base.generic.panels.ListTablePanel.<init>(ListTablePanel.java:44)
    at org.gui.base.main.internal.WorkPanel.<init>(WorkPanel.java:28)
    at org.gui.base.main.internal.InternalPanel.<clinit>(InternalPanel.java:38)
    ... 3 more
```

Lines causing exception (In my source code) :

```
public static final WorkPanel WORK = new WorkPanel();
```

Goes to

```
super(new WorkTable(AllWork.getElements(), true, true, true, true, true, true, true),
            new WorkTable(AllWork.getElements(), true, true, true, true, true, true, true, true));
```

To

```
public ListTablePanel(RefreshableTable m, RefreshableTable t) {
    this.main = m;
    this.totals = t;

    setLayout(LayoutFactory.createLayout());

    JScrollPane pane = new JScrollPane(main);

    main.setAutoCreateRowSorter(false);

    totals.setFont(totals.getFont().deriveFont(Font.BOLD));
    totals.setEnabled(false);

    pane.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS);

    add(pane, LayoutFactory.newFactory().setFill(GridBagConstraints.BOTH).
            setY(0).setWeightX(1).setWeightY(1));
    add(totals, LayoutFactory.newFactory().setFill(GridBagConstraints.BOTH).
            setY(1).setWeightX(1).setInsets(new Insets(0, 2, 0, 17)));
}
```

The last piece of code in my source code is the construction of `JScrollPane`.

I don't understand why this exception is thrown.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Any time I see this:

> Running a swing application in java, and I got this exception in my program. It's worth noting that ***this does not show up every time I run the program.***

Alarm bells go off in my head, and I think "am I handling Swing threading correctly"? Because it is not uncommon for Swing thread mishaps to cause strange errors that don't always occur.

So, are you handing Swing threading correctly, by first of all initiating and displaying the Swing GUI on the event thread? i.e.,

```
private static void createAndShowGui() {

  // create and display my GUI here

}

public static void main(String[] args) {
  SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
     public void run() {
        createAndShowGui();
     }
  });
}
```

By the way, you're not using Nimbus or another look and feel?

Comment: First, yes I handle all GUI changes and initializing in the EDT. Second, I am using Nimbus look and feel. Is this related?

Comment: Just wanted to add, I had the same thought about it not happening every time. Just wanted to ask if this kind of thing is a bug or something I am doing wrong.

Comment: Verify EDT with [`ThreadCheckingRepaintManager`](http://weblogs.java.net/blog/alexfromsun/archive/2006/02/debugging_swing.html).

Comment: @joelg236 if you handle all changes and initializing in the EDT, why does the stacktrace contains a `JScrollPane.<init>` entry and the thread name is `main`. This means the scrollpane is not initialized on the EDT

Answer (score 1):

Fixed the error. Found out I was doing GUI stuff simultaneously in the EDT. Constructors took too long to use `invokeLater()`, started using `invokeAndWait()`.

Comment: Can you elaborate on _simultaneously in the EDT_? That seems a contradiction.

Comment: haha, yes. Well, the `invokeLater` being called in the constructor was being called dangerously close to another method called `refresh`. The `refresh` method was changing things in the GUI that did not exist yet, and ended up messing things up. It only happened sometimes (most of the time) because sometimes the EDT prioritized the constructor (not prioritized, per say, but got around to doing it) before the refresh method, _sometimes_. Hopefully that makes sense.

Comment: Sadly? I am really relieved I figured that out. First year programming :)